# Solving a one-sided limit algebraically

Tags: limits

Consider:

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow(-1)^+} a^{\frac{2}{a+1}}$$

How does one solve such a one-sided limit algebraically?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to substitute (-1) to a?

Comment: @DavideMarano : Clearly, substituting gives $\frac{2}{0}$

Comment: sorry i saw $\frac{2}{a^{a+1}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $a=\frac{1}{n}-1$ where $n \to \infty$, you have:

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow(-1)^+} a^{\frac{2}{a+1}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{2}{\frac{1}{n}-1+1}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n}=e^{-2}$$

Comment: Note that this solution just says that if there exist a limit what it is, and do not say that the limit exists.

Comment: I disagree. The limit of $(1-1/n)^n$ is well-known and easy to show.

Comment: @martycohen That is OK. But if for a function one says that $f(a_n)$ is convergent for some known sequence $(a_n)_n$ converging to $a$, it doesn't mean it converges for all sequences converging to $a$. That is the point.

Comment: @martycohen please find my previous comment!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Define $f(x) = \frac{2 \ln x}{x+1}$ and use the famous [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Solution: 
From L'Hôpital's rule, one has
$$ 
\lim_{x\downarrow -1}f(x) = \lim_{x\downarrow -1} \frac{2 \ln x}{x+1}
= \lim_{x\downarrow -1} \frac{2 \frac{1}{x}}{1}
= \lim_{x\downarrow -1}  \frac{2}{x} = -2.
$$
Thus, again from L'Hôpital's rule, the limit $\lim_{x\downarrow -1} g(x)$, where $ g(x)= e^{f(x)} = x^{\frac{2}{x+1}}$ is defined and $\lim_{x\downarrow -1} g(x)=e^{-2}$.